# Apple Script: cannot call id3tag from script with "do shell script"

Tags: macos, bash, script

Trying to rename mp3s from an apple script which will be part of a larger script including Audio Hijacker.

```
set folder_p to "/Users/me/Music/"
set folder_path to POSIX path of folder_p
set file_path to ("\"" & folder_path & "one.mp3" & "\"")

do shell script (" id3tag " & " -AHEROR" & file_path)
```

The last command yields this error message:

```
error "sh: id3tag: command not found" number 127
```

When I call id3tag directly from the command line this works but in the script it fails. Any ideas what to do? I installed id3tag with brew.

Comment: Looks like id3tag isn't in the path the script uses. Perhaps you should link to the exact location?

Comment: So the binary is here: /usr/local/Cellar/id3lib/3.8.3_1/bin  what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved. Thx.

```
do shell script ("/usr/local/Cellar/id3lib/3.8.3_1/bin/id3tag " & " -A HHHHHHH " & file_path)
```